# Issue with passing objects from FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

As I'm trying to pass objects from formBuilder to another AbstractControl function of typescript file.

But not able to accomplish while passing data.

---

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-password-validation-in-angular-5-4tk4qr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)  Here is the coding snippets

Main.component.ts

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { PasswordStrengthValidator } from './PasswordStrengthValidator';

let obj = {};
obj.passwordLength  = 12;
obj.lowercaseNo     = 3;
...

this.passwordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(obj.passwordLength),
      Validators.maxLength(30),
      PasswordStrengthValidator
    ])),
  }, {
    validators: this.password.bind(this)
  });
}
```

PasswordStrengthValidator.ts

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export const PasswordStrengthValidator = function (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log(obj); // object values needs to be displayed here
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to achieve replacing the above code to the main component itself or are there any better way to get around this issue

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you try to set a minimal reproducible problem with a clear objective to achieve?

Comment: @Guilhermevrs [Click Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-password-validation-in-angular-5-4tk4qr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) Please refer to `PasswordStrengthValidator.ts` and `app.component.ts` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a factory:

<

```
export const PasswordStrengthValidatorFactory = (passObject: any) => {
  return function(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    // In console required to display those values in the passObject
    console.log(passObject);

    return null;
  };
};
```

```js
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    console.log(this.passObject);
    this.myForms = fb.group({
      password: [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), PasswordStrengthValidatorFactory(this.passObject)])]
    });
```

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-password-validation-in-angular-5-drwbmj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Great!... I have called `this.myForms = fb.group({...` within another function because it'll override the initial value with empty array. By using `await` & `async` could this method be called after getting any response/ ending by other method say this method initailizes the param value before calling `this.myForms..` inside another method called in a sequence by means of `await` & `async`...